# Filter based results power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables -

Table 418k has a seller name of more than 5k and another table exception has a seller name of around 1k.

Table 418k -

| Seller name | data 1 | data 2 | data 3 | data 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sony | Two | Three | qaa | Two |
| Flipkart | Two | Three | Saasdony | Two |
| Amazon | Two | Three | asd | Two |

Exception table -

| Seller name |
| --- |
| Sony |

I have to publish the results based on the exception list as well as based on all 5k data.

Like first publishing on the entire 418k data and then based on exception list data.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking for. What is the expected result?

Comment: Hey Davide can you plz connect over zoom if possible?

Comment: You need to update your question so it is clear for others. You need starting data and a desired output.

Comment: I will update it. What about the zoom call?

Comment: Stack Overflow help is provided by volunteers. Zoom calls sound like paid consultancy.